# Wrong device name displayed in iTunes

Tags: ios, data-synchronization

Whenever I sync on any computer my 3G iPhone, it will recognize and sync but doesn't show my original name for the phone. How do I replace it?

Comment: I assume you're using iTunes to sync?

Answer (score 1):

In the iTunes source list, select the device, then click on its name again and hold the mouse button down until the device name becomes editable.

Comment: Right-click > Rename works too.